# Git clone fails with GnuTLS error

Tags: git

I tried to clone the git repository on github by `git clone https://github.com/git/git.git` on ubuntu 16.04, 
but it failed with a fatal GnuTLS error.

With verbose log,

```
$ GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git clone https://github.com/git/git

Cloning into 'git'...
* Couldn't find host github.com in the .netrc file; using defaults
*   Trying 192.30.252.123...
* Connected to github.com (192.30.252.123) port 443 (#0)
* found 173 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
* found 697 certificates in /etc/ssl/certs
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* SSL connection using TLS1.2 / ECDHE_RSA_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
*    server certificate verification OK
*    server certificate status verification SKIPPED
*    common name: github.com (matched)
*    server certificate expiration date OK
*    server certificate activation date OK
*    certificate public key: RSA
*    certificate version: #3
*    subject: 
*    start date: Thu, 10 Mar 2016 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: Thu, 17 May 2018 12:00:00 GMT
*    issuer: C=US,O=DigiCert Inc,OU=www.digicert.com,CN=DigiCert SHA2 Extended Validation Server CA
*    compression: NULL
* ALPN, server accepted to use http/1.1
> GET /git/git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack HTTP/1.1
Host: github.com
User-Agent: git/2.8.2
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Accept-Language: en-US, *;q=0.9
Pragma: no-cache

* GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.
* Closing connection 0
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/git/git/': GnuTLS recv error (-54): Error in the pull function.
```

I found some reports for `GnuTLS recv error (-9)`, but I could not found information about `(-54)`.

On the other hand, I succeeded to clone my private repository by SSH protocol like `git clone git@github.com:iTakeshi/...`

I confirmed that git, curl, and GnuTLS library are updated to the latest version.

What's wrong about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me unbelievably long to solve this (close to 4 months!). I don't know why this happens for some machines but anyhow, your machine tries accessing github with your credentials, but since you don't have them, it throws that vague error.

To provide the credentials to your machine:

1. Go to your home folder and `ctrl + h` to show the hidden folders. Or if you love the terminal, paste the following: `nano ~/.netrc` or `gedit ~/.netrc`, depending on your text editor
2. In your `.netrc` file, add the following:

   ```
       machine github.com

       login YOURGITHUBUSERNAME

       password YOURGITHUBPASSWORD

       machine api.github.com

       login YOURGITHUBUSERNAME

       password YOURGITHUBPASSWORD
   ```

Now whenever you'll be pushing to git, you won't be prompted to provide your username or password again!

You can include your raw password there but for security purposes, generate an auth token here [github token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use/) and paste it in place of your password.

Hope this helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem with different repo. The key was that I run my devel linux vm on virtualbox. After update to virtualbox 5.1.10 the problem solved.

See this ticke for more https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16084.